# What better way to implement this idea on a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, performance, dataframe

I have a  pandas dataframe called Df which contains 26,000 rows. This dataframe includes 10 columns called "first price", "second price" and .... "tenth price".
I want to create a new column called "y" to this dataframe like this
For example, the 26th row of the "y" column indicates the name of the column whose value in row 26 of that column is closer to the number of the first column (the column whose name is the first price) of the 27th row(26+1) than the elements of the other columns in the 26th row.
I implemented this code with an algorithm, but this algorithm works very slowly for a sample of 1000, let alone 26,000!

```
y=[]
for i in range(1000):
    y.append((abs(df[df.index==(i)]-df["first price"][i+1])).idxmin(axis=1)[i])

for i in range(1000,len(df)):
    y.append(0)
df["y"]=y
```

Do you know a better way?

Comment: "closer" how? above or below?

Comment: a is closer to b than c whenever we have:       abs(a-b)<abs(b-c)

Comment: an example output might help as it is impossible to understand what you mean from the explanation

Answer (score 1):

You want to reshape the data to make it tidy. It's not good to have a bunch of columns all with the same value type (first price, second price, etc.). Better to have the type in its own column and the price beside it. Since you are comparing everything to the first price, you can leave it in its own index column and melt the rest of the columns into pairs of 'price number' and 'price' before finding the minimum of each 'item' (or what you had as rows in your example):

```
# example data:
np.random.seed(11)
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(range(100), (6,4)),
                   columns=['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'])
      .rename_axis('item_id')
      .reset_index())

# reshape data to make it easier to work with
df = df.melt(id_vars=['item_id', 'first'], var_name='price_number', value_name='price')

# calculate price differences
df['price_diff'] = (df.price - df['first']).abs()

# find the minimum price difference for each item
df_closest = df.loc[df.groupby('item_id')['price_diff'].idxmin()]
```